# Get a row value based on criterias - T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, cursor

[Sample Data in Yellow the desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nL6CC.jpg)

Just need your expert help on this.

I need to get the output based on T-SQL. Whenever the `invoice_line_id_link` is 0 put the `product_id` value if not look into the `id` column and get the `product_id` of that row.

Here's the script.

```
declare @t table
(id int, invoice_id int, product_id int, invoice_line_id_link int);

insert into @t values
(53,10,383,0),
(54,10,344,53),
(55,10,920,53),
(57,10,384,0),
(58,10,359,57),
(59,10,242,57),
(60,10,284,0); 

select id, invoice_id, product_id,invoice_line_id_link,  null desiredoutput from @t
```

based on the image if possible to populate using TSQL
[image]

Comment: Please don't use images but present in a consumable format - like so  https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Please read [ask] and [the accepted answer to "Why not upload images...?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) and [edit] your question accordingly. Sample data is best provided as DDL+DML (Create table and insert into statements). Desired output is best provided as formatted text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the image you have provided , here is the piece of code producing desired output.

Table Populate

```
declare @t table (id int, invoice_id int, product_id int, invoice_line_id_link int);

insert into @t values (53,10,383,0), (54,10,344,53), (55,10,920,53), (57,10,384,0), (58,10,359,57), (59,10,242,57), (60,10,284,0);
```

Code for Output

```
select *,CASE WHEN invoice_line_id_link = 0 THEN product_id
ELSE (select t1.product_id from @t t1 where t1.id = t2.invoice_line_id_link) 
END from @t t2
```

Output

```
id  invoice_id  product_id  invoice_line_id_link    desiredoutput
53  10  383 0   383
54  10  344 53  383
55  10  920 53  383
57  10  384 0   384
58  10  359 57  384
59  10  242 57  384
60  10  284 0   284
*/
```

Comment: Run using my actual data saying cannot update duplicate record if using subquery.

Comment: What exactly you want to update, can you please be a bit more specific.